# Weblogic Transaction Timeout : how to set in admin console in WebLogic AS 8.1

Tags: transactions, weblogic

I face the following exception:
weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 300 seconds

this is set within the Stateless Session EJB Bean as 
javax.transaction.UserTransaction jtaTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(300)
but I cannot figure out, where in the application console to set this property.

Comment: If you are not able to set timeout with console, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17580412/1782379).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After logging in, on the home page of the Server Console you should see 3 sections:

- Information and Resources
- Domain Configurations
- Services Configurations

Under **Services Configurations** there is subsection **Other Services**. Click the **JTA Configuration** link under **Other Services**. The transaction timeout should be the top setting on the page displayed, labelled **Timeout Seconds**.

[image: Weblogic Console screenshot]

Answer (score 28):

Had the same problem, thanks **mikej**.

In WLS 10.3 this configuration can be found in **Services > JTA** menu, or if you click on the domain name (first item in the menu) - on the **Configuration > JTA** tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Weblogic **9.2** the configuration via console is as follows:

[image]

I believe the default value was `60`.
Remember to use `Release Configuration` button after you edit the field.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the domain-wide default timeout, your best option is to change the deployment descriptor by setting the trans-timeout-seconds attribute in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jta/trxejb.html

This overrides the "Timeout Seconds" default, only for this specific EJB, while leaving all other EJB unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible at application level. Click on the EJB under the deployment(like Home > >Summary of Deployments >). Click on the Configuration tab and there  is "Transaction Timeout:"

Comment: There is no such thing there ...it is session timeout

Comment: That option doesn't exist in WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

The link above is rather outdated. For WebLogic 12c you may define the transaction timout in a transaction-descriptor for each EJB in the WebLogic deployment descriptor weblogic-ejb-jar.xml, see [weblogic-ejb-jar.xml Deployment Descriptor Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#EJBPG488).

For a message driven been it looks like this:

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>TestMessageBeanLow</ejb-name>
    <message-driven-descriptor>
        <pool>
            <max-beans-in-free-pool>1</max-beans-in-free-pool>
        </pool>
        <destination-jndi-name>jms/ActiveMQ/TestRequestQueue_LOW</destination-jndi-name>
        <connection-factory-jndi-name>jms/ActiveMQ/TestConnectionFactory</connection-factory-jndi-name>
    </message-driven-descriptor>
    <transaction-descriptor>
        <trans-timeout-seconds>60</trans-timeout-seconds>
    </transaction-descriptor>
    <resource-description>
        <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>jms/ActiveMQ/TestConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```