# Could not save Weblogic JTA settings via admin console

Tags: java, weblogic, administration

I'm trying ti increase JTA transaction timeout via admin console, but getting next error:
[image]

Why does it happen? Any ideas?

Also, if you know how could I change timeout without using admin console, please suggest.

**EDIT 1:**

Tried to use WLST, result is exactly the same

**EDIT 2:**

Tried to recreate new admin, result is exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost sounds like a weblogic bug. Posting as an answer because I bet it will work:

Bring down your domain

Go to your domain_home/config folder and edit the config.xml file

Search for and change the following to your desired timeout:

```
<jta>
<timeout-seconds>30</timeout-seconds>
<completion-timeout-seconds>120</completion-timeout-seconds>
</jta>
```

See if you can bring your domain back up. If not, can you post a larger picture or copy/paste the stack trace? It is fairly hard to read. Also, which version of weblogic?

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! It really works! But I want to add, that <jta> tag works (in my case) only if it is next to <security-configuration>, possibly it is XSL requirements.