# timeout error on weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I want to run a web application on a cluster.There are 2 servers(10.0.0.32 and 10.0.0.192). When I try to run this application on 10.0.0.192 I am getting below error.

By the way I am using adminserver on 10.0.0.32. I can control server 10.0.0.192 without any problem from 10.0.0.32 adminserver.

```
####<Dec 30, 2013 3:02:36 PM EET> <Error> <HTTP> <dell-PC> <10-0-0-192> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1388408556025> <BEA-101083> <Connection failure.
java.io.IOException: A complete message could not be read on socket: 'weblogic.servlet.internal.MuxableSocketHTTP@4bd7f3dd:Socket[addr=/10.0.0.32,port=55179,localport=7002] - idle timeout: '30000' ms, socket timeout: '5000' ms', in the configured timeout period of '60' secs
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer$TimerListenerImpl.timerExpired(SocketMuxer.java:1076)
at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:293)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Please check the below link it may be useful...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307154/weblogic-transaction-timeout-how-to-set-in-admin-console-in-weblogic-as-8-1

Comment: @TataraoVana I changed jta but timeout error still continues. I can control 10.0.0.192 server without error I mean I can start-restart-stop that server from 10.0.0.32 adminconsole but I couldn't deploy any application to 10.0.0.192 from 10.0.0.32 adminconsole.

Comment: While deploying what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: @TataraoVana Same error in the question. When I open server monitoring tab it says "This server is not currently reachable. No additional monitoring information is available." but I can control this server(start-restart-stop).

Comment: Try restarting the server which controls other server....Tail the logs for any other warnings or errors...

Comment: @TataraoVana I restarted but there is no error. At server 10.0.0.32 under ..\user_domain\servers\ there are folders named 10.0.0.32 and adminserver. At server 10.0.0.192 there are folders named 10.0.0.192 and adminserver. Is there any problem here?

Comment: 1) Did you deploy successfully before and this is a new problem, or  never successfully deploy to 10-0-0-192?   2) did you try to delete deploy first, then deploy again?

Comment: @BMW I never successfully deploy to 10.0.0.192. I can deploy project locally without any problem.(I mean I can deploy project for 10.0.0.193 from 10.0.0.193 adminconsole and I can deploy project for 10.0.0.32 from 10.0.0.32 adminconsole but I cannot deploy project for 10.0.0.192 from 10.0.0.32 adminconsole and vice versa)

Answer (score 2):

### Cause:

The above error indicates that the default configured timeout period of '60' secs is not sufficinet to transfer the complete message to the server.

### Resolution:

Increase the Complete Message Time Out to 480 seconds in weblogic console:

Server --> Protocols --> General -> Advanced Attributes -> Complete Message Timeout

You must reboot the server.

A complete message could not be read on socket: 'weblogic.rjvm.t3.T3JVMConnection'" on WebLogic :
weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is: java.io.IOException: A complete message could not be read on socket: 'weblogic.rjvm.t3.T3JVMConnection@12c22dd4', in the configured timeout period of '60' secs
at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.sendReceive(BasicOutboundRequest.java:108)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.java:284)

for this we can increase timeout period by setting the parameters

-Dweblogic.CompleteT3MessageTimeout=

-Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=

Comment: Still got same error. There must be something wrong with my managed servers I think.

Comment: Try this....

you can set the client version on the command line of the client:

-Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=480

Comment: I set complete message timeout on both servers. Same error "......in the configured timeout period of '480' secs......"

Comment: Seems to be a socket bug...

check the below link it may be useful...

http://3y.uu456.com/bp-09bcsc0e6c8sec3a87c2cs94-1.html

Comment: "telnet 10.0.0.32 7002" seems ok but "telnet 10.0.0.32 55179" says "couldn't open connection to host". What is port 55179 and how can I edit this port number?

Comment: what I found is under monitoring-general tab it says "This server is not currently reachable. No additional monitoring information is available."

Comment: oh k got you..you need to bounce the admin node then you will get that dynamic information.Try to bounce both admin and managed nodes once...It's good practice

Comment: Is that one is a windows server or linux server?

Comment: If it is windows then Goto Start -> Run
type wf.msc -> firewall will open -> goto inbound rules -> add new port...do telnet then it must have to open a connection...

Comment: You can change the listen port as per your requirement. This task can be accomplished in two diffrent ways. By changing config.xml file By changing in admin console Change the listen port in config.xml as per your requirement and bounce the domain. Admin Console Login to AdminConsole->Server->Configuration->ListenPort (Change it) Note: It is a bad practice to edit config.xml and try to edit in admin console(It's a good practise as well)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44334/discussion-between-hellzone-and-tatarao-vana)

Comment: in Windows you must have to enable that port in order to access from outside