# Consume Web-services from EJB - Configure Timeout (Weblogic)

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, ejb, weblogic

I'm having a problem set timeout to invoke a webservices from a EJB Client.
Using Weblogic as container.

***[edit]***
Web Services isn't in the same server, if I setup a JTA timeout its rolling back jta transaction without exception without cancel the previous call.
This process starts from a MDB, when JTA expires it consumes the JMS again and again and again and each web services invoking keep alive in WS Sever.

***[/edit]***

That was my steps:

1. Created stubs with wsimport
2. Created a proxy class to invoke webservice
3. Called webservice from a EJB.

Timeout settings:

```
    // Setting timeout
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) getService();
    Map<String, Object> context = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
    context.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
    context.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 20000);
```

If I invoke method from a stand alone program (like Swing, o a simple main) it works and throws a SocketTimeoutException, but from EJB don't respect the timeout.

Also tried to set a annotation to EJB method, but not worked either.

```
    @AccessTimeout(value=2000)
```

Any idea how to setup timeout calling from a Weblogic EJB?

Comment: try the instructions shown in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307154/weblogic-transaction-timeout-how-to-set-in-admin-console-in-weblogic-as-8-1

Comment: @Oldskultxo Thank you for answer, but the webservices isn't in the same server, if I setup a JTA timeout it will rollback jta transaction without exception and not will cancel the previous call, this process starts from a MDB, when JTA expires it consumes the JMS again and again and again and each web services invoking keep alive in WS sever . Any way thx